# UIImageView: add tap event from Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I know how to programmatically add a gesture recognizer. I was wondering how come when i Ctrl+drag from a UIImageView in the Interface Builder into the code, I'm only given the possibility to link Outlets and Outlets collections but not actions. I have enabled user interactions on the image view, so I would like to know id it's possible to access its actions in a "drag to add" way.

Comment: You need to add a UIGestureRecognizer from the objects palate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting user interactions enabled only allows the image view to work with gesture recognizers. They have no IBAction because they don't allow touch on their own. You would have to drag a gesture recognizer onto the image view to get it to work.

From the [UIImageView class ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/):

> Image views ignore user events by default. Normally, you use image views only to present visual content in your interface. If you want an image view to handle user interactions as well, change the value of its userInteractionEnabled property to true. After doing that, you can attach gesture recognizers or use any other event handling techniques to respond to touch events or other user-initiated events.